# Youtube search and get more 30 results with bs4

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, youtube, request

I use this code for yt search, but maximum results is 30, how can i get more(100, for example) results?
Also sometimes in `response` only `{"reload":"now"}`, what it mean?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.parse
import json


def search(search_request):
    encoded_search = urllib.parse.quote(search_request)
    BASE_URL = "https://youtube.com"
    url = f"{BASE_URL}/results?search_query={encoded_search}&pbj=1"
    response = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")
    results = parse_html(response)

    print(len(results))
    return results

def parse_html(soup):
    results = []
    for video in soup.select(".yt-uix-tile-link"):
        if video["href"].startswith("/watch?v="):
            video_info = {
                "title": video["title"],
                "link": video["href"],
                "id": video["href"][video["href"].index("=")+1:]
            }
            results.append(video_info)
    return results

search('backing track')
```

Comment: you might want to take a look at pytube, which could help you with youtube related python tasks, instead of parsing it via bs

Comment: @Tom looked in documentation of pytube, but don't find search function

Comment: https://pytube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html
would the "search" function here work?
client.video_search(q=None, **query)
Returns a VideoStream of videos matching the query parameters. You can perform a basic search very simply:

vids = c.video_search('search terms')

Comment: @Tom oh, sory, i looked PyTube3 lib, thinked it's pytube for third python

Comment: BeautifulSoup itself won't help you much as it will only parse the webpage, which loads dynamically... I guess you could look at Selenium's webdriver?

Comment: I thinked about selenium, but it's too slow for my goals

Comment: @TheHalf-BloodPrince is right, selenium would be a better choice here. Also you can watch the browser while it is processing so you could see where its going wrong (visual debugging haha). When everything works you can also use a headless browser then, their performance is faster. With multithreading you could also run several browsers at the same time

Comment: If Selenium won't work, and unless you want to be using YouTube's API (which out of sheer guess should give more than 30 results), you will need to be using a Javascript Engine to load the content that is intended to load dynamically. You can do so using a headless browser, which various Python packages implement. I don't know any much but Spynner (https://github.com/makinacorpus/spynner) is one of them.

Comment: I want to use something like pytube, but it is dead and does not work lib, and PyTube3 seems to be for download only